# Create dynamics names with for

Tags: r, loops

¡Hello!

I want to assign variables names.

I did this:

```
SCIAN is a data frame

SCIAN"i", for i in 1:20 are filtred data frames

for(i in 1:20){
assign(paste("SCIAN", i, sep = ""), subset(ISFLSH, SCIAN==i) )
}
```

Now, I want the conditional mean from selected vectors from differents data frames `(SCIAN1, SCIAN2...SCIAN20)`

Something like that but with loops.

```
SCIAN1<-sum(SCIAN1$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN1$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN2<-sum(SCIAN2$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN2$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN3<-sum(SCIAN3$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN3$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN4<-sum(SCIAN4$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN4$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN5<-sum(SCIAN5$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN5$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN6<-sum(SCIAN6$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN6$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN7<-sum(SCIAN7$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN7$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN8<-sum(SCIAN8$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN8$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN9<-sum(SCIAN9$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN9$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN10<-sum(SCIAN10$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN10$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN11<-sum(SCIAN11$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN11$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN12<-sum(SCIAN12$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN12$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN13<-sum(SCIAN13$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN13$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN14<-sum(SCIAN14$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN14$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN15<-sum(SCIAN15$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN15$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN16<-sum(SCIAN16$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN16$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN17<-sum(SCIAN17$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN17$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN18<-sum(SCIAN18$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN18$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN19<-sum(SCIAN19$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN19$INGOCUP!=0))
SCIAN20<-sum(SCIAN20$INGOCUP)/length(which(SCIAN20INGOCUP!=0))
```

I need help.

Thanks and sorry for my horrible english.

Comment: Use a vector: put the dataframes in a list. So SCIAN1 for example would be in `SCIAN[[1]]`

Comment: You are better off doing this `L = split(ISFLSH, list(ISFLSH$SCIAN)); lapply(L, function(x) sum(x$INGOCUP)/length(which(x$INGOCUP!=0)))`

Comment: Thank you. It really works. My problem is that I forgot to think with vectors solutions. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Vlo Or `with(ISFLSH[ISFLSH$INGOCUP != 0, ], tapply(INGOCUP, SCIAN, mean))`